# Can I get pip to delete scripts that I installed but no longer want?

Tags: python, setuptools

Say I have the following project:

```
confectionary/
    __init__.py
    confections.py
scripts/
    crunchy_frog.py
    anthrax_ripple.py
    spring_surprise.py
```

And it has been installed by my users, so they can simply type

```
$ spring_surprise.py
```

and have stainless steel bolts spring out of their computer, piercing both cheeks.

However, Constable Parrot has convinced me to move into more *conventional* areas of confectionary, so I will no longer offer such sweetmeats. I have changed my scripts to look like this:

```
scripts/
   praline.py
   lime_coconut.py
```

Yet, when I install this newer version, the old scripts stay around.

Is it possible to specify somehow in my setup.py that I no longer want these old scripts when my application is upgraded?

Comment: you could just uninstall and then re-install, of course.

Comment: @dbliss Yes, but that would assume that it's *my* machine - or did you mean have pip uninstall & reinstall?

Comment: Yeah, I meant use pip to uninstall and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is via setuptools. The delightful [Click library has a great example](http://click.pocoo.org/4/setuptools/#setuptools-integration).

Rather than having a `scripts` directory, simply combine that information in the application itself somewhere, so `confections.py` should contain something like this:

```
def crunchy_frog():
    '''Only the freshest killed frogs... '''
    # TODO: implement

def anthrax_ripple():
    '''A delightful blend of Anthrax spores... '''
    # TODO: implement

def spring_surprise():
    '''Deploy stainless steel bolts, piercing both cheeks'''
    # TODO: implement
```

Then in `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='confectionary',
    version='1.0.0',
    py_modules=['confectionary'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        crunchy_frog=confectionary.confections:crunchy_frog
        anthrax_ripple=confectionary.confections:anthrax_ripple
        spring_surprise=confectionary.confections:spring_surprise
    ''',
)
```

And when you change it up, obviously you'll change `confections.py` appropriately, but then you can change your `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='confectionary',
    version='2.0.0',
    py_modules=['confectionary'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        praline=confectionary.confections:praline
        lime_coconut=confectionary.confections:lime_coconut
    ''',
)
```

Now everything will be happy! And as an added bonus, you'll find that setuptools will create the [appropriate files](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) on Windows as well.

Delicious!